# Android - java.lang.NullPointerException in Frgment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, post

i'm new and i want to devellop an app that connect on a server and then a bottombar is displayed.
For this i am using a fragment (because next i will have further more fragments) , and when i click on a button , will connect and then set Visible the bottombar.
I can connect to the server ,  and ave a response but i am not able to display the bottombar, i have this error :

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

I know it is on tis line : menu.Connecté(c.getString("id")); but i don't know how to fix it..

Can you help me? Thanks
Here is my code:

```
public class FragmentConnexion extends Fragment {

    String ip = "http://MYIP/php";
    MainActivity menu = new MainActivity();
    TextView identifient,motdepasse;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.connexion, container, false);
        identifient = (TextView) myView.findViewById(identifiant);
        motdepasse = (TextView) myView.findViewById(mdp);

        Button connecte = (Button) myView.findViewById(button);
        connecte.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Connexion();
            }
        });
        return myView;
    }

    public void Connexion(){
        final String mPseudo= identifient.getText().toString();
        final String mMdp = motdepasse.getText().toString();
        final HttpGetRequest requete = new HttpGetRequest();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void run() {
                requete.execute(ip+"/utilisateur/affichage_id.php?pseudo="+mPseudo+"&mdp="+mMdp);
                try {
                    if(requete.get() != null){
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(requete.get());
                        JSONArray jSon = jsonObj.getJSONArray("valeurs");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jSon.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = jSon.getJSONObject(i);
                            if (!Objects.equals(c.getString("id"), "null")){
                                Log.i("ID",c.getString("id"));
                                menu.Connecté(c.getString("id"));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }
}
```

And the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String identifiant;
BottomBar bottombar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    BottomBar bottombar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
    bottombar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    bottombar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {
            if (tabId == R.id.tab_reveil) {

                Log.i("Reveil","Selectionné");
            }

            if (tabId == R.id.tab_whiz) {
                Log.i("Whiz","Selectionné");
            }

            if (tabId == R.id.tab_param) {
                Log.i("Paramètre","Selectionné");
            }
        }
    });


}

public void Connecté(String id){
    identifiant = id;
    bottombar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `((MainActivity)getActivity).Connect(c.getString("id"))`
and `BottomBar bottombar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);` change to `bottombar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);`

the `menu` in your fragment is a `new MainActivity()`,so the `bottombar` is `null`

Comment: Ok i've made your changes and now i have this error:  android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: I add a runOnUIThread  in the Connecté method and it work perfect! Thank again for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think, your bottomBar is null, probably, because you do not have a widget with "@+id/bottomBar" in the activity_main.xm

Comment: Hi! Nop it is not null , because i can set it visible on the mainActivity and it is displayed.